# Update only the relevant documents in the various Elastic indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have just started working in Elastic and was wondering if there is a native function that updates documents in all the indexes they are in when I need to update a value in a document.
For example: Index Asset
This index contains the provider attribute (name of the provider application), organisation and group.
Currently, if the name of one of these entities were to be changed, the documents containing the old values would only be updated in the entity's index (Asset index).

I would not like to solve the problem by updating all the indexes because that would consume too many resources. I would like to find a way to update only the documents containing the updated field in the various indexes. Thank you for your help